# I cannot make a reverse connection

Tags: linux, firewalls, ctf, reverse-shell

I am playing with a Linux CTF server and came across a kind of reverse connection block. I uploaded a php webshell, gained control of `www-data` user and tried to make a reverse shell.

Possible a UFW block at 1024~UP ports. In this server, I have SSH, FTP and HTTP services. Both SSH and FTP are ports above 1024. I have no ICMP communication between me and the machine, just loopback, even the Machine Gateway I cannot ping it.

So, if I can establish a HTTP session, I think which outbound port 80 is allowed, só I upload a new reverse shell php `https://github.com/pentestmonkey/php-reverse-shell` (That's what I thought) and triggered from website, by click, by curl, I thought this way the machine source connection will be port 80, but even so, that does not work.

Does anyone have an idea? How I can bypass this block?

Comment: If you already manage to get a webshell running on the server, what is the point getting a reverse shell?

Your assumption that TCP/80 outbound is allowed is false IMHO, the firewall in front of the server should allow inbound TCP/80, point.

Comment: We have no detail on the server, so we're guessing. And it's a CTF, so you cannot trust that it is configured in a standard way. It sounds like you need to map out the firewall (or use your shell to read the firewall config ...)

Comment: @Naoy, I have output limitions, example, sudo. Always I have a webshell a try to get to reverse shell. The server is allowed both in and out TCP/80. Do you think that I should to try to escalate the privilege through web shell?

Comment: @schroeder I do have no permission with www-data user.

Comment: then you need to map out the firewall